# Android Progress bar not showing up

Tags: android, progress-bar

```
private Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        removeDialog(0);
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case SUCCESS:
                Log.i("LoginActivity", "Got inputstream");
                final InputStream is = (InputStream)msg.obj;
                if (is != null)
                {
                    //TODO: examine the input stream, etc...
                }
                break;
            case FAILURE:
                Log.i("LoginActivity", "Login failed");
                //TODO: Failure handling
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            return dialog;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void loginRequest(String name,String password)
{   
    showDialog(0);
    loginThread thread = new loginThread(serverURL, name, password,getMyIMENumber(), handler);
    thread.start();
}
```

...............

```
public class loginThread extends Thread {

String name;
String password;
InputStream is;
String Url;
String ime;

private final Handler handler;

   public loginThread(String Url,String name,String password,String ime,final Handler handler) {
       this.name = name;
       this.Url = Url;
       this.password = password;
       this.ime = ime;
       this.handler = handler;         
   }


   public void run() {
          try{
                  HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                  String loginURL = Url+"member/login";
                  HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
                  HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
                  List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                  if(name.contentEquals(""))
                  {
                      pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ime", ime));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", name));
                      pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));                            
                  }                  


                  int timeoutConnection = 3000;
                  HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, timeoutConnection);
                  // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT) 
                  // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
                  httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
                  HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);                           
                  HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                  final InputStream is = entity.getContent();

                  Message message = new Message();
                  message.obj = is;
                  message.what = server.SUCCESS;
                  handler.sendMessage(message);
          }catch(Exception e){  
              Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString(), e);
              handler.sendEmptyMessage(server.FAILURE);
          }           

   }
```

}

Progress dialog doesn't show up what am i doing wrong here!! please help me..

......................

// Compiled from DexFile.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public final class dalvik.system.DexFile {

// Method descriptor #8 (Ljava/io/File;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public DexFile(java.io.File file) throws java.io.IOException;
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc  [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 4]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: file index: 1 type: java.io.File

// Method descriptor #18 (Ljava/lang/String;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public DexFile(java.lang.String fileName) throws java.io.IOException;
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc  [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 5]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: fileName index: 1 type: java.lang.String

// Method descriptor #22 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;I)Ldalvik/system/DexFile;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public static dalvik.system.DexFile loadDex(java.lang.String sourcePathName, java.lang.String outputPathName, int flags) throws java.io.IOException;
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc  [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 6]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: sourcePathName index: 0 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: outputPathName index: 1 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: flags index: 2 type: int

// Method descriptor #28 ()Ljava/lang/String;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public java.lang.String getName();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc  [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 7]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile

// Method descriptor #30 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public void close() throws java.io.IOException;
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc  [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 8]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile

// Method descriptor #32 (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;)Ljava/lang/Class;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 3
  public java.lang.Class loadClass(java.lang.String name, java.lang.ClassLoader loader);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc  [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 9]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: name index: 1 type: java.lang.String
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: loader index: 2 type: java.lang.ClassLoader

// Method descriptor #37 ()Ljava/util/Enumeration;
  // Signature: ()Ljava/util/Enumeration;
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public java.util.Enumeration entries();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc  [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 10]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile

// Method descriptor #30 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  protected void finalize() throws java.io.IOException;
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc  [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 11]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile

// Method descriptor #42 (Ljava/lang/String;)Z
  public static native boolean isDexOptNeeded(java.lang.String arg0) throws java.io.FileNotFoundException, java.io.IOException;
}

Comment: can you post the code for showProgressDialog() method.

Comment: public void showProgressDialog(){
  mDialog = ProgressDialog.show(server.this, "", 
                "Please wait...", true);
  mDialog.setCancelable(false);
 }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You retrieve the `InputStream` from your thread right away, it's more than likely that it still is null, or has its initial value, didn't get the http response yet. This way your progress dialog is shown for a few milliseconds at most.

End your `loginRequest` after calling `thread.start()`, and from within your thread's `run` method communicate if you got the result or any exception towards the UI thread using a `Handler`. In the handler's `handleMessage` check for the outcome of the `loginRequest` (the result input stream would be better to be passed to the handler directly, than to retrieve it from the thread), and remove your progress dialog.

**Update**
Here is a sample how to achieve what you want using threads:
In the code below your main activity is referenced as `LoginActivity` (since I don't know the name of your class), so you should change it to whatever the name of the java activity class is, where you have the `loginRequest` method.

Remove the `showProgressDialog()` method from your main activity, and instead put:

```
public static final int FAILURE = 0;
public static final int SUCCESS = 1;
private ProgressDialog dialog;

private Handler handler = new Handler()
{
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg)
    {
        removeDialog(0);
        switch (msg.what)
        {
            case SUCCESS:
                Log.i("LoginActivity", "Got inputstream");
                final InputStream is = (InputStream)msg.obj;
                if (is != null)
                {
                    //TODO: examine the input stream, etc...
                }
                break;
            case FAILURE:
                Log.i("LoginActivity", "Login failed");
                //TODO: Failure handling
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
};

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case 0:
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            return dialog;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

public void loginRequest(String name, String password)
{
    showDialog(0);
    LoginThread thread = new LoginThread(serverURL, name, password, 
        getMyIMENumber(), handler);
    thread.start();
}
```

Note, that the `loginRequest` method has changed!
So did your `LoginThread` class:

```
public class LoginThread extends Thread
{

    private final String name;
    private final String password;
    private final String url;
    private final String ime;
    private final Handler handler;

    public LoginThread(String Url, String name, String password, 
        String ime, final Handler handler)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = Url;
        this.password = password;
        this.ime = ime;
        this.handler = handler;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String loginURL = url + "member/login";
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(loginURL);
            HttpParams httpParameters = new BasicHttpParams();
            List<NameValuePair> pairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            if (name.contentEquals(""))
            {
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ime", ime));
            }
            else
            {
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userName", name));
                pairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            }

            int timeoutConnection = 3000;
            HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpParameters, 
                timeoutConnection);
            // Set the default socket timeout (SO_TIMEOUT)
            // in milliseconds which is the timeout for waiting for data.
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(pairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            final InputStream is = entity.getContent();

            Message message = new Message();
            message.obj = is;
            message.what = LoginActivity.SUCCESS;
            handler.sendMessage(message);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString(), e);
            handler.sendEmptyMessage(LoginActivity.FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Now your `LoginThread` instance has a new member of type `Handler`. It is initialized via a constructor parameter (as the others), so you can have it declared `final`.
This handler will notify your UI thread (main activity), if it has got the input stream from the http response, or if it failed for some reason. 
Complete the `Handler` implementation, to get it do what you need.

I hope the code cleared up a bit this approach.

Comment: can you explain me this please

Comment: thank you so much, this is clear to understand, i m goin to try this... will let you know the result.

Comment: i made the change as shown above and i also edited my Question
.... but i m getting this error now... cant run the application

Comment: // Compiled from DexFile.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public final class dalvik.system.DexFile {
  
  // Method descriptor #8 (Ljava/io/File;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public DexFile(java.io.File file) throws java.io.IOException;
    0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]

Comment: // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public DexFile(java.io.File file) throws java.io.IOException;
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 4]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: file index: 1 type: java.io.File
  
  // Method descriptor #18 (Ljava/lang/Str

Comment: it s not even goin to onCreate() in my activity

Comment: Please paste the stack trace as addition to your question (though this would be an other issue), because this (i have no idea what this is) is not readable. Also make sure you have your androidManifest.xml correct.

Comment: That's a weird error, please try to clean up your project. If the androidManifest.xml is correct, and the `server` class is set as your main launcher activity, but when debugging, the `onCreate` doesn't even get called, the problem is not with the code above. It might be something in your androidManifest, and also something sticked in which can be helped by a Project->Clean...

Comment: i reloaded the project and its workin awesome... thank you soo much for your patience and help

Comment: Really glad, to hear that, happy coding further! :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't call `thread.run()` but `thread.start()`.

`run()` calls the function `run()` on the same thread. `start()` will call it in a new thread. currently the GUI thread is blocked because it performs action that should be done in background thread.

You can either call the thread by:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new loginThread(serverURL, name, password,getMyIMENumber()));
thread.start();
```

Or make your loginThread **extend** Thread instead of implementing Runnable.

Comment: The method start() is undefined for the type loginThread
getting this error

Comment: public void start(){
     this.run();
    }
i added this to make start work

Comment: "yes you did" what? my suggestion or what you commented?

Comment: now loginThread extend Thread.... and i am using loginThread.start();
still same problem i couldnt see progress dialog

Comment: Than don't get the response using this method, instead use a handler to receive this information from the thread. There are many good tutorials about using handlers, look in SO and you'll have what you need.

Comment: can you provide a link. i have no idea about handlers

Comment: look at this example in android site: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html

Comment: i changed my code(also edited above) but now i couldnt run the application

Comment: // Stack: 3, Locals: 2 public DexFile(java.io.File file) throws java.io.IOException; 0 aload_0 [this] 1 invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1] 4 new java.lang.RuntimeException [2] 7 dup 8 ldc <String "Stub!"> [3] 10 invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4] 13 athrow Line numbers: [pc: 0, line: 4] Local variable table: [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: dalvik.system.DexFile [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: file index: 1 type: java.io.File // Method descriptor #18 (Ljava/lang/Str

Comment: Please update the question and add error log there, it's hard to read like that.

Answer (score 0):

unless and until you call the show method of the progress Dialog it will not show up.

```
do this in your showProgressDialog method -- mDialog.show();
```

Comment: The cleanest way to this this kind of operation is by using AsyncTask.Use onPreExecute() to show your ProgressDialog, doInBackground to do your stuff and onPostExecute to dismiss your ProgressDialog. --- http://www.brighthub.com/mobile/google-android/articles/82805.aspx