# Show ProgressDialog while uithread sleeps?

Tags: android

I want to show ProgressDialog while uithread sleeps so that until the data from the server is retrived my activity will not be shown. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Thread`, `AsyncTask`, or `Service` to load your data in the background, and with a `Handler` implementation control your `ProgressDialog`.

[The example in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5814170/android-progress-bar-not-showing-up/5814313#5814313) shows how to use a thread for a login request, and in the meantime show the progress dialog.

Using `AsyncTask` is a lot easier and clearer:

```
private static final int WAIT = 11;
private final class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Show up the dialog with id=WAIT [11]
        showDialog(WAIT);
        // other actions that must be performed in the UI thread
        // before the background works starts
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params)
    {
        // perform the background work
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
    {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // Remove the dialog with id=WAIT [11]
        removeDialog(WAIT);
        // other actions that must be performed in the UI thread
        // after the background works finished
    }
}

[...]

final MyTask task = new MyTask();
task.execute(null);
```

Since `AsyncTask` is a generic type, you can specify the parameter types for your preference, so it is very handy for transferring data from the ui thread to a background thread and back.

Your dialog part is just a few lines inside your activity:

```
private ProgressDialog dialog;

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    switch (id)
    {
        case WAIT:
        {
            dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
            dialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            dialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            return dialog;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This task is commonly solved with AsyncTask bounded with progress dialog. See this [article](http://it-projects.spb.ru/?p=150&lang=en).

Answer (score 0):

Move your Network Process code into a `Thread` and get a `ProgressDialog`. Start your network process by calling `.start();` and then `ProgressDialog.show();`  when you have done in network process, stop the `ProgressDialog` through a `Handler` from `Thread.run()`.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code for progress dialoge in ur thread

ProgressDialoge pd = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...", "Retrieving data.", true,false);